# Finding unicode characters in system font in swift for setting attributed titles in buttons

Tags: swift

I am doing cs193p and for my homework I need to tweak around with the unicode characters that are only available in system font. How do I find these unicode characters in Xcode to set them as attributed titles on the buttons in my UI.

Comment: I'm seeing you are new here, so some good practices are:
- Look for questions similars;
- Put some code on your question;
- Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Last but not less important: keep the community.

Comment: Hi @Rhidita... keep in mind to evaluate the answer. If you think the answer is useful and it is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Lopes Did already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an unicode char as button title like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testButton: UIButton!
// ...

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  testButton.setTitle("", for: UIControlState.normal)
}
```

If you have an specific unicode, you can try that:

```
testButton.setTitle(String("\u{20e0}"), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: why not simply `testButton.setTitle("\u{20e0}", for: .normal)`

Comment: Because for someone who is starting ... it is good practice keep in mind from where is coming some properties. But you are completely right @LeoDabus, we can just suppress the `UIControlState`. thanks for bringing it to us.

Comment: No need to use the String initializer